# Tableau: Heat map with two "Points of interest"

Tags: geocoding, heatmap, tableau-api

First off - sorry I can't attach an excel file or CSV with the proper data, but I'll write it in here as best I can.

Basically, I want to generate a heatmap that has two fixed points layered atop. These two fixed points are generated using coordinates I've created. I've been able to do with with ONE fixed point, using a double axis, but not sure how to add the other point. That dataset looked like this:

```
zip    count  place1     LONG        LAT     place2             LAT2      LONG2
95020   120   MY HOME   -122.9011   37.3326  FRIENDS HOME   37.335895   -121.99833
95122   90    MY HOME   -121.9011   37.3326  FRIENDS HOME   37.335895   -121.99833
94086   66    MY HOME   -121.9011   37.3326  FRIENDS HOME   37.335895   -121.99833
95127   163   MY HOME   -121.9011   37.3326  FRIENDS HOME   37.335895   -121.99833
```

To generate the one fixed point I did the following:

1. Added `LONG` and `LAT` measure to Columns and Rows TWICE
2. Made both a dual axis
3. This created two "Marks" - `LAT` and `LAT(2)`.
4. I added `sum(COUNT)` and `ZIP` to `LAT`
5. I made `LAT(2)` the "Circle" type, as opposed to "Filled Map" for `LAT`
6. Changed colors
7. Results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Vbf.png

How can I add a circle for `LAT2` and `LONG2?`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, a sample workbook can be shared to try resolving the issue as the explanation is not clear.